# How to solve error with pre-create check when runnig docker quickstrat terminal?

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, docker-quickstart-terminal

I am trying to install on my "WIN10 Home" the Docker Toolbox. When executing the docker quickstart terminal, I am getting this error:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VirtualBox is configured with multiple host-only adapters with the same name \"HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter\". Please remove one"
```

Comment: if any of the answers solved your issue please accept the appropriate answer to share the resolution with the community. If not please provide further information or share your own solution. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you need to remove one of your host-only network adapters in VirtualBox due to the fact that there are 2 with the same name

"HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox"

and that you should manually remove one.
You can do that either with the UI or via commandline

```
vboxmanage hostonlyif remove "HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox"
```